# Serving images from two different directories with Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, files, directory, regex

This should be basic... I'm brand new, and no amount of googling and searching stack exchange is helping.

I have a website that I want to be able to serve images from, from different directories. I think the easiest way to do that would be to map something like website.com/i/image.jpg to a folder at root/i/, and put the images in there and be done with it.
So something like this should work, no?

```
location /i/ {
  /i/$uri;}
```

I don't know, I'm having a really hard time understanding nginx syntax.
But I also want to keep the URL as short as possible, and I believe I could do some fancy logic with regex where I can call images from /i/ while not messing with images that get called from root, or other folders. But I am just so stumped at syntax.

I saw on some other posts on stackexchange people trying to capture a string, and I realized that if I make all the image's names fit a certain pattern, I could attack it with a regex location that should match 100% of the time, so I can keep the url short and still separate the images from ones that I have no use with (I would explain their difference in purpose but I feel like it would be off topic).

Anyway, I saw the post with

```
location ~ "^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,6})$" {...
```

and realized this could be close to what I need. All of my files for this location will be 6 characters long, a-z only, and followed by any extension. I thought this would be simple, and I could do something like

```
location ~ "^([a-z]{6})$" {...
```

But no matter how I mess with the syntax, I just can't get it to run.
Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: This is not clear: "map something like website.com/i/image.jpg to a folder at root/i/, and put the images in there and be done with it." These don't seem to quite correspond to URLs or directory structures. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm having people upload files to my website, which is a file host. Right now, the files they upload just get tossed into the websites root directory. It would be much cleaner if I could just put them somewhere like root/i/, one directory higher, but I can't manage to do this with a location without also increasing the length of the URL. Does that make sense? I'm trying to come up with a clever way to have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion based on `ALex_hha`'s answer and the details in `farfie`'s comment above.

```
server {
    listen      8989;
    server_name www.example.net;

    root /vhosts/www.example.net/public_html;

    location ~ "^/([a-z]{6})(.*)\.(jpg|png|svg)$" {
        rewrite ^/([a-z]{6})(.*)\.(jpg|png|svg)$" /vhosts/www.example.net/static/$1$2.$3;
    }
}
```

The key is to use nginx `rewrite` directive to capture essential parts from the URI so that it can be mapped to any directory.

The `root` directive only changes the document root, and the URI is appended to the document root as-is, which in this case is not what you want.

Comment: Another interesting take, but I still wasn't clear enough. I settled on this:
location ~ "^/([a-z]{6})\.(.*)$" {
try_files /images/$uri =404;} If I understand correctly, this will look for files in /images/ that match the 6 a-z characters before the extension and then any extension length/type. If nothing is found, it will leave the block and try another location block. Is this right? And may I ask why you guys seem to be avoiding try_files?

Comment: I wasn't avoiding it, just didn't remember its existence :) That is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
server {
    listen       8989;
    server_name  www.example.net;

    root /vhosts/www.example.net/public_html;

    location ~ "^/([a-z]{6})(.*)\.(jpg|png|svg)$" {
        root /vhosts/www.example.net/static;
    }
}
```

And upload all images to the /vhosts/www.example.net/static. With settings above

www.example.net/qwerty/test.png would be translated ->  /vhosts/www.example.net/static/qwerty/test.png

Comment: I think this is close, but I think I really did need to type out my entire case. Right now, people upload their file to mydomain.com, and they get domain.com/file.ext in return. As it is, the files all get placed in the root directory, just because I can't figure out some regex logic to have them put into another directory without making the URL longer, like mydomain.com/public/file.ext. Your regex logic should be helpful though, could you explain what each part does? I find this so difficult to find information on. The ^, why you're using both / & \, two dots... I don't get it.

Comment: In regex, there are many special characters. `^` means beginning of the string, `.` means any character, `+` means one or more times the previous character, `*` means zero or more times the previous character. To match a specific special character, one has to escape it with `\`. So, in the above case, `^` means that the URI must start exactly with `/`, then have six characters between a-z, then any character zero or more times. Then, there must be a literal `.` for the extension, which is either `jpg`, `png` or `svg`. I recommend that you read some tutorial on Regular expressions.

Comment: Highly recommend http://regex101.com/ to play with any regex

Comment: @ALex_hha
>regex101.com
Wow nice, now we just need to build on top of this to make nginx101.com if you catch my drift.